# Installing SQL Server 2012 Standard on a machine with more than 64GB RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I’m in the process of doing the specification for a new server that will host SQL Server 2012 including  SSIS, SSRS and SSAS

I’m aware SQL Server 2012 Standard has a limit of 64GB. However from what I’ve been reading today it looks like that limit is just for the database engine and we can install SQL Standard on a machine that has more than 64GB Ram; and SSIS, SSRS have their own separate 64GB limit.

Can anyone confirm that my understanding is correct?

thanks!

Comment: yup you're  right. keep in mind that the other services (integration and reporting) use their own memory space. The memory limit you are talking about only applies to the DB engine, so make sure the server has enough to fully utilize the DB engine plus the other services running on the machine.

Comment: just for information purposes - https://ozar.me/2014/03/good-news-sql-server-standard-editions-limits/